# Synchronizing a bunch of text data very often - is compression is a good pattern?

Tags: android, synchronization, compression

I am wondering if I have to synchronize very often (every hour) a bunch of text data - for example 10kb - won't it better to compress it before sending ?

For example if I compress it and then send to my server, where it will be uncompressed and handled - application will use less transfer. Is it good pattern to work with this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that depends on your problem set.  If it's small, it might be better to compress and send the whole thing.  If it's not small, you may want to consider an [rsync](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync) style solution that only transmits the required amount of data to bring the file in sync.  You still may want to do compression on the wire, but you wouldn't want to rsync a compressed file because a small change might cascade into a larger one with compression.

The link matters too, as does cost and power consumption.  Compression algorithms vary, but it will take more CPU time than not compressing.  Hopefully, at the cost of a much reduced send time, which ultimately saves you power.

So, given the problem set you're talking about, a small file, I think it's nice to compress it and send it across, particularly if a link is slow (which they sometimes are when you have bad reception).  I'm not familiar with Android's framework, but you may get this for "free" if you're POSTing a file via HTTP, and both ends support gzip compression.